# How can I get the source of the button and get this to work?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

```
package game;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public interface Listeners 
{   
    static PatternGame game = new PatternGame();
    InputGame game2 = new InputGame();
    static class inst implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("inst".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {

            }
        }
    }
    static class play implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("play".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {
                menu.mf.dispose();
                PatternGame.gameStart();

            }
        }
    }
    static class exit implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("exit".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    static class input implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (InputGame.numOfClicks != 0)
            {
                InputGame.button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                InputGame.button.setText("X");
                InputGame.numOfClicks--;
            }
            else
            {
                if (InputGame.checkCorrect())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like another pattern?");
                    PatternGame.order++;
                    PatternGame.gameStart();
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect!");
                    menu.start();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
package game;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class InputGame implements Properties,Listeners{
    public static JFrame gf = new JFrame();
    public static JButton button = new JButton();
    public static int height = 800;
    public static int width = 600;
    public static int gsize = 4;
    public static int order =1;
    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(height,width);
    public static menu Menu = new menu();
    public static GridLayout Ggrid = new GridLayout(gsize,gsize);
    public static int numOfClicks =0;
    public static int numCorrect=0;
    public static int[][] input = new int[][]{
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}

    };

    //public static Thread d;


    public static void setup() {
        gf.dispose();
        gf = new JFrame();
        gf.setLocation(300,100);
        gf.setSize(size);
        gf.setResizable(false);
        gf.setLayout(Ggrid);
        gf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PatternGame.clear();
        blank();
        gf.setVisible(true);
        System.out.print(numOfClicks);

    }

    public static void blank()
    {
        for (int a =0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for (int b =0;b<4;b++)
            {
                button = new JButton("");
                button.setActionCommand("");
                button.addActionListener(new input());
                gf.add(button);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void input()
    {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                String x = button.getText();

                if (x.equals("X"))
                {
                    input[a][b] = 1;
                }
                else if (x.equals(""))
                {
                    input[a][b] = 0;
                }
                System.out.println(input[a][b]);

            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkCorrect()
    {
        input();
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                if (order == 1)
                {
                    if (handlebars[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("X");
                        InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
                if (order == 2)
                {
                    if (ys[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
                if (order == 3)
                {
                    if (spaceShip[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
                if (order == 4)
                {
                    if (flock[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
                if (order == 5)
                {
                    if (percent[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
                if (order == 6)
                {
                    if (square[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    InputGame.numOfClicks++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Ok, this is my code. Now what I want the program to accomplish is for the program to display the blank screen(which I have done) then when the user clicks one of the buttons and it places a X on that button. Then after 6 clicks for the program to translate the pattern they put in to the input array, so I can compare the input array to the pattern array, and be able to tell the user if its correct or not and move on. What this program does now is it displays the blank screen then when a button is pressed it displays the X. I got it to check for one button but I don't know how to check for all of them. So how could I check each button for the text it holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call getComponents() on the parent container- whether panel, frame or window and then check if it is an instance of button, then check the text set on it like this:

```
Component[] comps = parent.getComponents();
for(Component c:comps){
    if(c instanceof JButton){
        JButton btn = (JButton) c;
        String text = btn.getText();
        //Use text for whatever, add it to an array or something
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea